# 'Accessed JObject values with invalid key value: 1. Object property name expected.'

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to get JSON data from an api.

I have this json with me:

```
{
    "elements": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Bob",
            "address": "abc street",
            "hobbies": {
                "indoor": "Games, reading books",
                "outdoor": ""
             }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Mark",
            "address": "def street",
            "hobbies": {
                "indoor": "Games, reading books",
                "outdoor": ""
             }
        } 
      ]
}
```

I have this code with me:

```
using(var httpClient = new HttpClient()) {

  HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync("api_url_here").Result;

  var studentJsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
  var Jsresult = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<dynamic>(studentJsonString).ToString();

  JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(Jsresult);

  IEnumerable<dynamic> listDyn = jObject[0].Select(items => new StudentModel// gives error here as whole
  {
        id = items["id"].ToString(),
        name = items["name"].ToString(),
        address= items["address"].ToString()
  });
}
```

But when I am calling the above method but it is giving me an error:

> 'Accessed JObject values with invalid key value: 1. Object property name expected.'

What am I missing?

Comment: FYI: `JavaScriptSerializer` was deprecated around a decade ago. Don't mix `JavaScriptSerializer` with JSON.NET, it's only going to cause you headaches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you deserializing twice? The result of

```
JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(customerJsonString)
```

is already an object. You don't need to parse it again with `JObject.Parse()`. You can just do

```
JObject jObject= JObject.Parse(customerJsonString)
```

Furthermore the result of `JObject.Parse()` is a dictionary and not an array. It has properties, which you can access by their names. For instance

```
jObject["elements"]
```

But of course, the compiler can't possibly predict, that `jObject["elements"]` will be an `IEnumerable`, so you will have to make sure of that.

```
jObject.Value<JArray>("elements").Select(item => ...)
```

This reads the property `elements`, of `jObject` as a `JArray`.